# C - fprintf not printing to file when in a while loop with an incrementing counter

Tags: c, eclipse, file

I am a beginner at C using Eclipse, and am trying to read 2 file and write it so that there are 4 words on each line. This code belongs to a function and I am calling it on 2 different files. I have opened and closed the input file **fin** and the output file **fout**. Both files exist.

```
char word[15];
int i = 0;
while (fscanf(fin, "%s", word) != EOF) {
    fprintf(fout, "%s ", word);
    i++;
    if (i > 3) {
        fprintf(fout, "\n");
        i = 0;
    }
}
```

This code works if I write to console instead of a file. However, when I run it as shown here so that it writes to the output file, nothing is written in the file. Printing **word** to file has no issues without the incrementation of **i**.

I've printed out the values of **i** and **word** to console directly after the incrementation, and it appears that i is being reset correctly. File 1 appears to have been read completely and written to console, but nothing was written to the output file. For file 2, the code prints everything to console correctly until it hits a comma, and nothing is written to output. When the comma is removed, a few lines of file 1 are written to file and file 2 prints but nearly all the words are missing letters.

What is wrong here? I'm not sure if there's a local issue because this code worked a few hours ago. Thank you.

Comment: Are you calling `fclose` on `fout` when you're done with it?

Comment: You should use version control.  You say it was working a few hours ago.  You could either see what changes were made since then or revert back to a working copy.

Comment: `while (fscanf(...) != EOF)` should be `while (fscanf(...) == 1)`. And `char word[15];` seems risky. There are words with more than 14 letters. I'd be generous and use `char word[100];` The worst thing that can happen in C code is writing past the end of an array, so you should never risk that.

Comment: @dbush Yes, directly after this code block

Comment: @FiddlingBits Thanks, I will set up Github

Comment: @user3386109 Thank you! That was it, I was using 15 because I falsely assumed that none of the file words would surpass that length. I was told to use EOF, but I will look into the == 1

Comment: Minor style thing:  Use `fputc('\n', fout);` instead of `fprintf(fout, "\n");`. The latter is overkill for a single character.

Comment: Good, I'm glad you got that sorted out. Let me give you some info about the `== 1`. The return from `scanf` is the number of successful conversions, or EOF if the end-of-file is reached before any conversions are performed. So if one conversion is requested, as in your code, a return value of 1 indicates success, and any other value indicates failure. Which is why `== 1` is recommended. Having said all that ... due to the way `%s` works, you should only ever get 1 or EOF. If you were using `%d` the return value could be 1, 0, or EOF. So `== 1` will always work, `!= EOF` only works with `%s`.

Comment: @user3386109 That's good to know, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Issue solved, there were words in the file longer than 14 chars and didn't fit correctly into my string variable.